# Filling array from text file and then writing them in console C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Here is my code.. 
exercise asked to write those integers into file, then open the file and fill the two dimensional array with those integers from file and then print it on the console.

Here is the code I've written and after running it in Visual Studio 2010, it gave me strange errors... can you help me with that to examine whats the problem in the code?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\hi.txt", FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            string filepath = "C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\hi.txt";

            sw.WriteLine("6,73,6,71");
            sw.WriteLine("32,1,0,12");
            sw.WriteLine("3,11,1,134");
            sw.WriteLine("43,15,43,6");
            sw.WriteLine("55,0,4,12");
            sw.Close();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            int [,] data = new int[4,5];
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < data.GetLength(0); r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < data.GetLength(1); c++)
                    {
                      /* 
                        if (reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            return ricxvebi;
                        } 
                       */
                             data[r, c] = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }

            var rowCount = data.GetLength(0);
            var colCount = data.GetLength(1);
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\t", data[row, col]));
                Console.WriteLine();
            } 


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "strange errors"? Please be more specific.

Comment: you try open file that already open in line `using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))`

Comment: I removed StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
but still..

Comment: @GeoDrawkcab so provide error message

Comment: http://goo.gl/Hd4H13

here is the error message what it gave me after ctrl + f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed several of your codes in your program (comments will help you recognize them)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
    { 
        string filepath = "C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\hi.txt"; // use these as common
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine("6,73,6,71");
        sw.WriteLine("32,1,0,12");
        sw.WriteLine("3,11,1,134");
        sw.WriteLine("43,15,43,6");
        sw.WriteLine("55,0,4,12");
        sw.Close();
        string buffer = "";
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open); // changes are here in FileMode
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs1);
        int[,] data = new int[5, 4]; // your array index is short
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while ((buffer = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var row = buffer.Split(',');
            foreach (var rowItem in row)
            {
                data[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(rowItem); 
                j++;
            }
            i++; j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Filestream object you use is the same in both occurrences. In both cases it is trying to create the file because of the FileMode.Create. Try breaking it down separately such as this.

```
FileStream fs;
fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);

//Code to write to and close file

fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);

//code to read file to output
```

Answer (score 1):

- content of your file does not match your array
  use `int [,] data = new int[5,4];` instead of `int [,] data = new int[4,5];`
- `data[r, c] = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());` `ReadLine` returns all line i.e. `6,73,6,71`, so when you try parse it as int you get errors. For solve this for example you can use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/b873y76a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) functions
- from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : `File.OpenText(filepath)` is equivalent to the `StreamReader(String)` constructor overload.
- both `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` have overload constructors with parameter `string path`, so you don't need create new filestream instantly manualy. You can try something like this

---

```
string filepath = "C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\hi.txt";  
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath)){
        .... //your actions
}
....
using(StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(filepath)){
        .... //your actions
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sample for using `Split` function

```
var numbersInString = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i< numbersInString.Length;i++){
    var num = int.Parse(numbersInString[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering...
but I still couldn't figure out the piece of code with Split function while parsing integers with readline... can you help me with that>?